# How to navigate rows in interactive grid using next and previous buttons

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

May I know how to navigate rows in interactive grid using next and previous buttons in oracle Apex.
In my case I need to display always 1 row even there are multiple records fetch and allows to navigate next/previous row using buttons.

Comment: why interactive grid?

Comment: @EnriqueFlores Because, I wanted to show 2 IGs like master and detail. But instead of showing detail IG as a table, I need to show row by row using next/previous buttons. Any other approaches can also be suggested.